# Using vb.net to create card reader software cannot read and write image and display error message while using at windows 8 and 8.1

Tags: vb.net, dll

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim card As New GemCard
    If card.ReadCard Then



        Dim aFileStream As FileStream

        aFileStream = New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "photo.j2k", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim myBinaryWriter As New BinaryWriter(aFileStream)
        myBinaryWriter.Write(card.CivilIDApp.Photo("PHOTO").BinValue)

        myBinaryWriter.Close()


        Call ImageLoad()

        Photo.ImageLocation = Application.StartupPath + "photo.jpg"


    End If



    Button2.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You are using vb, so why did you add c# tag? What is the error message that you are talking in the title?

Comment: I am using C# also. While running my card reader s/w at windows 8 & 8.1  it will read text data except image file and display access denied path error message box. S/w working successfully  at windows 7. How can i overcome this problem ?

Comment: Ok, you are using C#, but in your question you just posted a vb.net code. Your question lacks details... How can people help you, if you do not accurately describe your problem? You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your information and help to rectify .

Comment: `it will read text data except image file and display access denied path error message box` you're reading/writing the image on `Application.StartupPath`. Most likely user doesn't have permission to write files on the location where your application is installed. Where are you reading text data from? Have you tried using that same path for images?

Comment: i tried both are same path, but still display the same error message .Reading both data from program files(x86). If any compile error then possible to change the target Cpu and overcome this issue. But still cant find out the error?